# Prevent function call from within specific functions

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a whole bunch of objects that are of classes that derive from a class with a member function called `Init()`:

```
class Object {
  public:
    Init();
};
```

And let's say I have a singleton object with a public method, e.g.

```
singleton.SomeFunction();
```

Is there a straightforward way I could prevent `SomeFunction()` from being called during the `Init()` method of any object of type Object, or derived from Object?

Comment: This seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I'd like something that I could catch this at compile time, e.g. with static_assert, so that it would be clear that SomeFunction() is inaccessible from within Init() functions, but can happily be called anywhere else

Comment: But _why_ don't you want to call functionA in functionB? Why are you worried about it?

Comment: You could make the function protected or private and use the friend clause to allow access from "everywhere else"... but as @RSahu mentioned, this seems like design smell, at least without more info on the bigger problem.

Comment: The creation of all the Object instances is data driven, and the order that they are all initialized is not known. The function that I'd like to ban during initialization of these objects belongs to an instance of one of these objects, which may or may not exist at this time.

Comment: Okay, definitely XY problem now.  The short answer to your question is: no, you can't prohibit function calls based on who the caller is unless, as @moodboom suggests, you set up visibility rules that localize access within your class or subclasses.  If you want some actual advice, then you should really provide a detailed example (with code) of exactly what you're doing and we can propose a different approach that you might not have thought of.

Comment: Essentially, I have a list of objects getting initialized. Some of them may try to access another object in the list (via the function I'd like to ban at this time) before that object has been initialized itself.

Comment: But the feedback so far seems to be that the entire premise is undesirable, which I can understand. Perhaps ordering the initialization of objects based on some sort of priority might be the way to go.

Comment: `Init()` looks like it goes against RAII

Comment: @JamesRoot You're right it does, which is unpleasant for sure. Trying to make the best of a bad situation ;)

Comment: Call me boring if you wish, but I'd just put DON'T CALL THIS FROM AN INIT METHOD in the docs, and do a bit of code review on the init methods if anyone else was involved in the dev work. Nice and straightfoward, no magic needed.

Comment: You can perhaps inject the objects into the singleton after they are initialized. Without knowing how your objects are maintained and what their relations to the singleton and to each other, I can't say for sure if that's feasible.